# How to compare two folders for similar files based on name in C#?

Tags: c#

I have two folders `A` and `B`..Inside A multiple files are there and inside B multiple files are there..I have to check files in A with files in B for identical files...
I tried like this for a particular file name

```
void DirSearch(string sDir)
        {
          List<string> lstFilesFound = new List<string>();
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
                    {
                        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d,"MsBuild_Tracker.proj")
                           {
                                lstFilesFound.Add(f);
                           }
                            DirSearch(d);
                    }
       }
```

It is working..I tried like this for two folders

```
foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
                {
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetDirectories(dDir))
                    {
                        foreach (string g in Directory.GetFiles(d, f))
                        {
                            lstFilesFound.Add(g);
                        }
                        DirSearch(d, f);
                    }
                }
```

It is not working...Any suggestion??

Comment: Do you mean *identical* filenames in different directories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using **.NET 4**, you can use `DirectoryInfo` and `EnumerateFiles()`. Then you can use LINQ to join the two directories to get the common files between the two directories.

```
var dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp1");
var dir2 = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp2");

var filesinboth = from f1 in dir1.EnumerateFiles()
                  join f2 in dir2.EnumerateFiles() on f1.Name equals f2.Name
                  select f1.Name;
```

or you can use `where` if you want additional conditions to apply.

```
var filesinboth = from f1 in dir1.EnumerateFiles()
                  from f2 in dir2.EnumerateFiles()
                  where f1.Name == f2.Name // and some other condition
                  select f1.Name;
```

These will both give you stream of `string`s. If you need the actual `FileInfo` instances, change the `select` part of the query to return `f1` instead of `f1.Name`.

If you're using **.NET 3.5**, you need to use `GetFiles()` instead, which returns `FileInfo[]`. So the queries will look like this:

```
var filesinboth = from f1 in dir1.GetFiles()
                  join f2 in dir2.GetFiles() on f1.Name equals f2.Name
                  select f1.Name;
```

and

```
var filesinboth = from f1 in dir1.GetFiles()
                  from f2 in dir2.GetFiles()
                  where f1.Name == f2.Name // and some other condition
                  select f1.Name;
```

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen:What namespace i have to use..i got this error

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen:system.io.directoryinfo doesnot contain a definition for enumeratefiles

Comment: @Bala3569: System.IO in .NET 4. I'll update my answer to reflect that. As you didn't tag your question with a specific version, I assumed you were using the latest.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen:is it possible to compare files using modified datetime

Comment: @bala3569: Yes, just add additional options to the where clause.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen:How to write fileinboth value in a text file like this dest.WriteLine(filesinboth);

Comment: @Bala: `File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\inboth.txt", filesinboth);`

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen:cant give like that bestoverload method for System.io.file.writeallline(string,string[]) has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen:string[] foo = filesinboth.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray(); worked

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen:how to get non identical files

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen:If u write like this where f1.Name != f2.Name it is giving whole search result

Comment: hello thank you Brian. is it possible to check for equality based not on file names, but on say a hash value? is this at all possible?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't use just something like this (without recursion) ?

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetMachingFiles(string pathA, string pathB)
{
    var matchingFiles = new HashSet<string>();

    var allAfiles = Directory.GetFiles(pathA, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (var file in allAfiles)
    {
        foreach (var mathcFile in Directory.GetFiles(pathB, Path.GetFileName(file), SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            matchingFiles.Add(mathcFile);
    }
    return matchingFiles;
}
```

Of course this solution suffers a performance decay in case of many files, because `Directory.GetFiles` navigates all files even when you pass a restrictive pattern.
To be more faster you could use LINQ as pointed out in [Brian Rasmussen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374887/how-to-compare-two-folders-for-similar-files-based-on-name-in-c/4375203#4375203)

**EDIT:**
a faster example using LINQ (.NET 3.5):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetMachingFilesFast(string pathA, string pathB)
{
    DirectoryInfo dirA = new DirectoryInfo(pathA);
    DirectoryInfo dirB = new DirectoryInfo(pathB);

    var filesA = dirA.GetFiles("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    var filesB = dirB.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    var matchingFiles = 
    filesA.Where(fA => filesB.Any(
                                  fB => fA.Name == fB.Name 
                                  // && fA.LastWriteTime == fB.LastWriteTime
                                 )
                 )
          .Select(x => x.Name);
    return matchingFiles;
}
```

Comment: Nice targeted solution, easily readable (not checked if it works ;))

Comment: Added a faster solution for completeness ;-)

Comment: can u alter ur code for selecting identical file for modified datetime along with name

Comment: Just uncomment the commented line ;)

Answer (score 2):

try below code , you need to change path of files

```
   DirectoryInfo dinfoTemp1 = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\Temp1");
        DirectoryInfo dinfoTemp2 = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\Temp2");

        FileInfo[] lstTemp1 = dinfoTemp1.GetFiles();

     List<string> ui  =   lstTemp1.Where(
                          x => dinfoTemp2.GetFiles().
                          Where(y => y.Name.Contains(x.Name)).Count() > 0).
                          Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are basically doing is:

```
setting directory to var d like C://
Setting directory to var f like My Documents
Getting files that have the name My Documents in C://
and if you find any which I highly doubt, you add it to your list.
```

The first one works because;

```
sets the directory to var d like C://
gets the file that is named MsBuild_Tracker.proj in C://
adds it to the list.
```

Tell us what you need and maybe we can help..

Comment: I need to compare files inside two folders and select identical files

Comment: You need to check for content, not the name then

Answer (score 1):

Maybe compare (for a non-linq version) --

```
namespace RecursiveDirCompare
{
    class Program
    {
        static List initialFiles = new List();

        static string initRoot = @"root";
        static string initCompare = @"compare";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory( @"C:\Temp\test\");
            initRoot = @"root";// args[0];
            initCompare = @"compare";// args[1];

            AddFilesToInitialList(initRoot);

            CompareWithInitialList(initCompare);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void AddFilesToInitialList(string root)
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(root))
            {
                initialFiles.Add(file.Replace(initRoot, ""));
            }
            foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(root))
            {
                AddFilesToInitialList(directory);
            }
        }

        static void CompareWithInitialList(string root)
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(root))
            {
                if(initialFiles.Contains(file.Replace(initCompare, "")))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file + " is found in both");
                }
            }
            foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(root))
            {
                CompareWithInitialList(directory);
            }            
        }
    }
}
```