# Find Missing files and sub directories with it's files list while copy and paste?

Tags: c#, .net, io

I copy the one folder which contains thousands of files from my pc to mobile.Due to some interference some of the files are not copied.But the folder size is nearly 1 GB.

So i check the folder size both of the folders(Sources as well as destination) having only some kb's size difference. If i copy that again means it's take some amount of time and i need to override the existing files.

Instead of that i need to list what are the files are missing then copy only the missing files. Can i make one simple exe tool for this. How to i find that missing files can any one give some guide to do. Don't mistake me if you feel it is fool question.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374887/how-to-compare-two-folders-for-similar-files-based-on-name-in-c

Comment: Maybe you can [`robocopy.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc733145.aspx). This small and simple tool is a must have and can solve a large number of issues. I have even seen this tools fired from C# code in some project versus a self made copy solution, because it's very powerful and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

> Can i make one simple exe tool for this.

Of course.

> How to i find that missing files can any one give some guide to do.

You need two lists. You'll need to read and fill one, and then read and compare to determine what's missing. The code might look something like this:

```
var targetFiles = new List<string>();
foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(targetDir))
{
    targetFiles.Add(Path.GetFileName(f));
}

var missingFiles = new List<string>();
foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
{
    if (targetFiles.Contains(Path.GetFileName(f))) { continue; }
    missingFiles.Add(Path.GetFileName(f));
}
```

Now all of the missing files in the target are in the `missingFiles` list. You can then loop through that list to copy those missing files to the target.

Comment: Michael - I think your code is the wrong way around. If `sourceDir` was originally copied to `targetDir` then `sourceFiles.Contains(Path.GetFileName(f))` will *always* be true - I think that actually you want to build a list of all the files in `targetDir` first, and then check `if (targetFiles.Contains...` in your second loop.  (Of course, I notice this *after* I upvoted you :-) I'll leave the upvote in place though!)

Comment: @DanPuzey, you are 100% right. I need another cup of coffee!! I will edit, and thank you very much.

Comment: No problem - I fully understand the perils of not drinking enough coffee!

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory linq version of code to retrieve your list of files that need to be copied:

```
var srcFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir).Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
var destFiles = Directory.GetFiles(destinationDir).Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));

var filesToCopy = src.Except(dest);
```

One caveat (with both this answer and Michael's) is that a nested directory structure would not be supported - if you have subfolders also being copied, this code will not work.

**EDIT** to include the code from the comments used for nested subdirectories...

```
var srcFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir,"*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(f => Path.GetFullPath(f).SubString(sourceDir.Length));
var destFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir,"*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(f => Path.GetFullPath(f).SubString(sourceDir.Length));

var filesToCopy = src.Except(dest);
var fullPathOfFilesToCopy = src.Except(dest).Select(s => Path.Combine(sourceDir, s));
```

Comment: There is an [overload of `Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) that is recursive: `Directort.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.*",`System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

Comment: @SteveB If he does use recursive search, he needs `Path.GetFullPath` to avoid name clashes as `Path.GetFileName` returns only the file name + extension part (ie `C:\a.txt` and `C:\folder\a.txt` will both be `a.txt`)

Comment: @SimonBelanger: indeed. Playing a bit with strings make this easily workaround: `var srcFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir,"*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(f => Path.GetFullPath(f).SubString(sourceDir.Length));`

Comment: Using just the filename and a recursive search is no good, because `"c:\src\test.txt"` should only match `"c:\dest\test.txt"` and not `"c:\dest\sub\test.txt".  However, `GetFullPath` on its own isn't enough: you'd have to strip the root folder from each path before you compare, else `"c:\src\test.txt"` won't match `"c:\dest\test.txt"`.  So... a little more complex.

Comment: @SteveB: exactly, and you typed that faster than I typed my own reply, too ;-)

Comment: it's working only with files. thanks for given solutions.One more thing i need to check with in sub folders file also. For this how to i do..

Comment: For this you read the comments immediately above the one you just posted, where we discussed how to solve that very problem...

Comment: sorry for the improper post. But i need to check it's sub directories also. How to i do for this kind of requirement.